# Installation Restrictions based on UWP App Min Version

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

I would like to know below info reg uwp apps.

1. I have built a UWP app with some API's that are allowed only from Win 10 RS4 and by default I kept app target min version as Win 10 RS1, however the app doesn't work on OS ver < RS4 and errors are captured in UI.

   But we have requirement to restrict installation itself of UWP apps on the versions lesser than target min version. I tried keeping min version same as target version (Win10 Rs4) but still app is getting installed.

   I would like to know how to restrict app installation itself on OS less than uwp app min version.
2. How to set privacy settings (Ex: enable camera access for specific apps) programmatically in uwp apps?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know how to restrict app installation itself on OS less than uwp app min version

The app can be installed if it's min version greater than OS version, For more please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/app-package-requirements#supported-versions).

> How to set privacy settings (Ex: enable camera access for specific apps) programmatically in uwp apps?

You can launch the settings applications on the location page to let the user activate the location both globally and for your application using the following URI: `ms-settings:privacy-webcam`.

```
bool result = await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings:privacy-webcam"));
```

For get all the available settings, please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app#privacy).